# Get all sticky posts from one user through user ID

Tags: wpdb, sticky-post

So I need to get number of sticky posts each user have and compare it to one variable. I managed to do this, but I am wondering is this the right way to do it.

```
 //Retrive all sticky posts ID
        $sticks = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->options WHERE option_name = 'sticky_posts'");
        $stickies = unserialize( $sticks[0]->option_value ); //array with the IDs of sticky posts
        // print_r($stickies);
        // Get user id from sticky post ID
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($stickies as $sticki) {
            $post_meta = get_post($sticki);
if($post_meta->post_author == $current_user->ID && $post_meta->post_status != 'trash' && strtotime($post_meta->post_date) > strtotime('-30 days') ) { $i++; }
        }
```

And $i is number of sticky posts for that user. So what I am doing is looping through all sticky posts, getting post meta for each sticky post and through post meta getting post author to compare it with current user id.

Answer (score 1):

Copy and paste this function into the function.php file under current
theme.

```
// Create a new filtering function that will add where clause to the query
function filter_where( $where = '' ) {
  // posts in the last 30 days
  $where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days')) . "'";
  return $where;
}
```

Paste it where you need to display.

```
$sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );
$args = array(
  'numberposts' => -1
  'post__in'  => $sticky,
  'author' => $current_user->ID
);
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );

// The Loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
  $the_query->the_post();

  echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';  

endwhile;
```

Comment: Thanks but that does not count number of sticky posts for a user ?